# Asp.net and Jquery return data bug

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have Jquery code behaves weirdly. I am doing a complex task but I am almost done with it. Only problem I have is I am trigering a webmethod in C# which works perfectly. That webmethod returns a string value. I am trying to set a cookie with that returned value but it displays [object Object]. How can I display the returned value properly.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "InsertPost.aspx/insert_post_new_category",
data: "{'CategoryName':'" + user_cat + "','CategoryDescription':''}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data, status) {
    if (user_cat.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') != '') {
        $("#demo-input-facebook-theme").tokenInput("add", { name: user_cat, id: data });
        $.session.set(encodeURIComponent('Kat_' + user_cat + '_x'), data);
    }
}
```

});

I am having problem with "data" above. that displays [object Object]. How can I fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you used `{dataType: "json"}` (in your options to $.ajax()) , because of that to access the value by using `data.d` instead of only data

Comment: what does "d" represents? I need to wait 10 mins to mark it as answeres. thank you very much, it works

Comment: @Borsel - data repsent json object and to get value of it you need to write data.d so is value of the object return by you..you can check jquery ajax function that will give you more clear idea

Answer (score 1):

That is because `data` is an `object`. Try using the correct property of the `object data`